# Setting up Dlib for Android on Windows

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, dlib

I am trying to set up `dlib` in android studio in windows following this tutorial, https://github.com/Luca96/dlib-for-android. I have changed path of various variables but get the same error. I do not need opencv just dlib. Opencv is already setup and working correctly.

I replaced `-GNinja` with `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe` and still get error.

**Any alternate procedure for setting up dlib with android studio will also work.**

My custom `Power Shell` script based on the sample provided:

```
# Luca Anzalone

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- DLIB FOR ANDROID: setup script
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Android-cmake path: REPLACE WITH YOUR CMAKE PATH!
$AndroidCmake = 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe'

# Android-ndk path: REPLACE WITH YOUR NDK PATH!
if (Get-Variable 'ANDROID_NDK' -Scope Global -ErrorAction 'Ignore') {
    $NDK = $ANDROID_NDK
} else {
    $NDK = 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669'
}

$TOOLCHAIN = "C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake"

# Supported Android ABI: TAKE ONLY WHAT YOU NEED!
# $ABIs = 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
$ABIs = 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

# path to stripper tool: REPLACE WITH YOURS, ACCORDING TO OS!!
$STRIPPER_PATH = "$NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin"
$STRIPPERS = @{
    'armeabi-v7a' = "$STRIPPER_PATH\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe";
    'arm64-v8a'   = "$STRIPPER_PATH\aarch64-linux-android-strip.exe";
    'x86'         = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;
    'x86_64'      = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;    
} 

# Minimum supported sdk: SHOULD BE GREATER THAN 16
$MIN_SDK = 24

# Android project path: REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT PATH!
$PROJECT_PATH = 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose'

# Directory for storing native libraries
$NATIVE_DIR = "$PROJECT_PATH\app\src\main\cppLibs"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Utils
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Make-Dir {
    if (-Not (Test-Path $args[0])) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $args[0] > $null
    }
}

function Copy-Directory ($from, $to, $tab) {
    $Items = Get-ChildItem $from

    ForEach ($item in $Items) {
        if ((Get-Item $item.FullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            Write-Host "$tab > $item"
            Make-Dir "$to\$item"
            Copy-Directory "$from\$item" "$to\$item" "$tab  "
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $to
            Write-Host "$tab | $item copied." 
        }
    }
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Dlib
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

# Dlib library path:
$DLIB_PATH = 'C:\Users\computer\Desktop\dlib-19.19'

function Compile-Dlib {
    Set-Location $DLIB_PATH
    Make-Dir 'build'

    Write-Host '=> Compiling Dlib...'
    sleep 0.5

    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: '$abi'..."
        sleep 0.5

        Make-Dir "build\$abi"
        Set-Location "build\$abi"

        $cmakeArguments = @(
                "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1",
                "-DANDROID_NDK=$NDK",
                "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TOOLCHAIN",
                "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe",
                "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
                "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-O3",
                "-DANDROID_ABI=$abi",
                "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-$MIN_SDK",
                "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=..\..\",
                "..\..\"
        )

        $stripArguments = @(
                "--strip-unneeded",
                "dlib/libdlib.so"
        )

        & $AndroidCmake $cmakeArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: '$abi'..."
        & $AndroidCmake --build .
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: '$abi'to reduce space..."
        & $STRIPPERS[$abi] $stripArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host '=> done.'
        Set-Location ..\..\
        sleep 0.5
    }    
}

function Dlib-Setup {
    Write-Host '=> Making directories for Dlib...'
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib' created."

    Write-Host "=> Copying Dlib headers..."
    Copy-Directory "$DLIB_PATH\dlib" "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib" ''

    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libdlib.so' for each ABI..."
    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Copy-Item -Path "$DLIB_PATH\build\$abi\dlib\libdlib.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Write-Host " > Copied libdlib.so for $abi"
    }
}

# COMMENT TO DISABLE COMPILATION
Compile-Dlib

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- OpenCV
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# OpenCV library path: REPLACE WITH YOUR OPENCV PATH!
$OPENCV_PATH='path-to-your\opencv-4.0.1-android-sdk\sdk\native'

function Opencv-Setup {
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv"

    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libopencv_java4.so' for each ABI..."
    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
        Copy-Item -Path "$OPENCV_PATH\libs\$abi\libopencv_java4.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
        Write-Host " > Copied libopencv_java4.so for $abi"
    }
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Project setup
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Make-Dir $NATIVE_DIR

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY DLIB '.so' FILES
Dlib-Setup

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY OPENCV '.so' FILES
Opencv-Setup

Write-Host "=> Project configuration completed."

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Partial Error log:

```
PS C:\Users\computer\Desktop\dlib-19.19\build> & "C:\Users\computer\Desktop\setup1.ps1"
=> Compiling Dlib...

=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: 'armeabi-v7a'...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Studio
  Edition' is not installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/computer/Desktop/dlib-19.19/build/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: 'armeabi-v7a'...
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: 'armeabi-v7a'to reduce space...
C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe: 'dlib/libdlib.so': No such file
=> done.

=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: 'arm64-v8a'...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Studio
  Edition' is not installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/computer/Desktop/dlib-19.19/build/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: 'arm64-v8a'...
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: 'arm64-v8a'to reduce space...
C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-strip.exe: 'dlib/libdlib.so': No such file
=> done.

=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: 'x86'...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Studio
  Edition' is not installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/computer/Desktop/dlib-19.19/build/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: 'x86'...
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: 'x86'to reduce space...
C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe: 'dlib/libdlib.so': No such file
=> done.

=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: 'x86_64'...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Studio
  Edition' is not installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/computer/Desktop/dlib-19.19/build/x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: 'x86_64'...
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: 'x86_64'to reduce space...
C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe: 'dlib/libdlib.so': No such file
=> done.
=> Making directories for Dlib...
=> 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose\app\src\main\cppLibs\dlib' created.
=> 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose\app\src\main\cppLibs\dlib\lib' created.
=> 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose\app\src\main\cppLibs\dlib\include' created.
=> 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose\app\src\main\cppLibs\dlib\include\dlib' created.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT: Use DLIB master from Github instead of 19.19 from their website to avoid errors with OpenCV. Change the paths accordingly, set `dlib-19.19` to `dlib-master` where applicable.**

I was able to compile `dlib` by making some changes to path and flags. A big change was to include both flags,

```
-GNinja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe"
```

I extracted latest `dlib(19.19)` to desktop and also setup `cmake`, `NDK`, `lldb`. Compiling for `x86_64` only,

```
C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -DANDROID_NDK="C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669" -GNinja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -DANDROID_ABI=x86_64 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions "C:\Users\computer\Desktop\dlib-19.19\CMakeLists.txt"
```

Run above code by pasting it into power shell. It will generate `libdlib.so` in dlib folder.

**Compilation Script:**

```
# Luca Anzalone

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- DLIB FOR ANDROID: setup script
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Android-cmake path: REPLACE WITH YOUR CMAKE PATH!
$AndroidCmake = 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe'

# Android-ndk path: REPLACE WITH YOUR NDK PATH!
if (Get-Variable 'ANDROID_NDK' -Scope Global -ErrorAction 'Ignore') {
    $NDK = $ANDROID_NDK
} else {
    $NDK = 'C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669'
}

$TOOLCHAIN = "C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake"

# Supported Android ABI: TAKE ONLY WHAT YOU NEED!
# $ABIs = 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
$ABIs = 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

# path to stripper tool: REPLACE WITH YOURS, ACCORDING TO OS!!
$STRIPPER_PATH = "$NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin"
$STRIPPERS = @{
    'armeabi-v7a' = "$STRIPPER_PATH\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe";
    'arm64-v8a'   = "$STRIPPER_PATH\aarch64-linux-android-strip.exe";
    'x86'         = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;
    'x86_64'      = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;    
} 

# Minimum supported sdk: SHOULD BE GREATER THAN 16
$MIN_SDK = 24

# Android project path: REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT PATH!
$PROJECT_PATH = 'C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\OpencvPose'

# Directory for storing native libraries
$NATIVE_DIR = "$PROJECT_PATH\app\src\main\cppLibs"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Utils
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Make-Dir {
    if (-Not (Test-Path $args[0])) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $args[0] > $null
    }
}

function Copy-Directory ($from, $to, $tab) {
    $Items = Get-ChildItem $from

    ForEach ($item in $Items) {
        if ((Get-Item $item.FullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            Write-Host "$tab > $item"
            Make-Dir "$to\$item"
            Copy-Directory "$from\$item" "$to\$item" "$tab  "
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $to
            Write-Host "$tab | $item copied." 
        }
    }
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Dlib
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

# Dlib library path:
$DLIB_PATH = 'C:\Users\computer\Desktop\dlib-19.19\dlib'

function Compile-Dlib {
    Set-Location $DLIB_PATH
    Make-Dir 'build'

    Write-Host '=> Compiling Dlib...'
    sleep 0.5

    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: '$abi'..."
        sleep 0.5

        Make-Dir "build\$abi"
        Set-Location "build\$abi"

        $cmakeArguments = @(
                "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1",
                "-DANDROID_NDK=$NDK",
                "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TOOLCHAIN",
                "-GNinja"
                "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe",
                "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
                "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-O3",
                "-DANDROID_ABI=$abi",
                "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-$MIN_SDK",
                "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=..\..\",
                "..\..\"
        )

        $stripArguments = @(
                "--strip-unneeded",
                "dlib/libdlib.so"
        )

        & $AndroidCmake $cmakeArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Generating the 'dlib/libdlib.so' for ABI: '$abi'..."
        & $AndroidCmake --build .
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: '$abi'to reduce space..."
        & $STRIPPERS[$abi] $stripArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host '=> done.'
        Set-Location ..\..\
        sleep 0.5
    }    
}

function Dlib-Setup {
    Write-Host '=> Making directories for Dlib...'
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib' created."

    Write-Host "=> Copying Dlib headers..."
    Copy-Directory "$DLIB_PATH" "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib" ''

    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libdlib.so' for each ABI..."
    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Copy-Item -Path "$DLIB_PATH\build\$abi\libdlib.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Write-Host " > Copied libdlib.so for $abi"
    }
}

# COMMENT TO DISABLE COMPILATION
Compile-Dlib

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- OpenCV: Not used in this
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# OpenCV library path: REPLACE WITH YOUR OPENCV PATH!
#$OPENCV_PATH='path-to-your\opencv-4.0.1-android-sdk\sdk\native'

#function Opencv-Setup {
#    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv"
#
#    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libopencv_java4.so' for each ABI..."
#    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
#        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
#        Copy-Item -Path "$OPENCV_PATH\libs\$abi\libopencv_java4.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
#        Write-Host " > Copied libopencv_java4.so for $abi"
#    }
#}


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Project setup
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Make-Dir $NATIVE_DIR

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY DLIB '.so' FILES
Dlib-Setup

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY OPENCV '.so' FILES
#Opencv-Setup

Write-Host "=> Project configuration completed."

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Save the above code into a power shell file with extension `setup1.ps1`. The above code should generate `libdlib.so` file inside `dlib-19.19/dlib/build` folder for each platform folder.

In order to run the code first open power shell as administrator. Next, use `set-location C:\Users\computer\Desktop\dlib-19.19`. Here use `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and press `A` to be able to execute powershell code. After all done(libdlib.so generated and copied) use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted`.

Run the power shell code by pasting `& "C:\Users\computer\Desktop\setup1.ps1"` into shell. It will take some time to compile and after compilation it will copy headers and `libdlib.so` for different platform to android studio project folder as in variable `$PROJECT_PATH` in script above.

Comment: i get the following error
& : The term 'C:\dlibAndroid\setup1.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "C:\dlibAndroid\setup1.ps1"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\dlibAndroid\setup1.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: the powerShell solution didn´t worked for me. i posted below a working solution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

@B200011011 solution didn't worked for me. I had to correct some output directories to make it work on windows 10 PowerShell.

Here´s the updated code:

```
# Luca Anzalone

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- DLIB FOR ANDROID: setup script
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Android-cmake path: REPLACE WITH YOUR CMAKE PATH!
$AndroidCmake = 'C:\Users\Aeon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe'

# Android-ndk path: REPLACE WITH YOUR NDK PATH!
if (Get-Variable 'ANDROID_NDK' -Scope Global -ErrorAction 'Ignore') {
    $NDK = $ANDROID_NDK
} else {
    $NDK = 'C:\Users\Aeon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147'
}

$TOOLCHAIN = "$NDK\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake"

# Supported Android ABI: TAKE ONLY WHAT YOU NEED!
$ABIs = 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

# path to stripper tool: REPLACE WITH YOURS, ACCORDING TO OS!!
$STRIPPER_PATH = "$NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin"
$STRIPPERS = @{
    'armeabi-v7a' = "$STRIPPER_PATH\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe";
    'arm64-v8a'   = "$STRIPPER_PATH\aarch64-linux-android-strip.exe";
    'x86'         = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;
    'x86_64'      = "$STRIPPER_PATH\x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe" ;    
} 

# Minimum supported sdk: SHOULD BE GREATER THAN 16
$MIN_SDK = 16

# Android project path: REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT PATH!
$PROJECT_PATH = 'C:\Users\Aeon\Desktop\AeonLabs\Software\Android\IOYO\code'

# Directory for storing native libraries
$NATIVE_DIR = "$PROJECT_PATH\app\src\main\cppLibs"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Utils
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Make-Dir {
    if (-Not (Test-Path $args[0])) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $args[0] > $null
    }
}

function Copy-Directory ($from, $to, $tab) {
    $Items = Get-ChildItem $from
    
    ForEach ($item in $Items) {
        if ((Get-Item $item.FullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            Write-Host "$tab > $item"
            Make-Dir "$to\$item"
            Copy-Directory "$from\$item" "$to\$item" "$tab  "
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $to
            Write-Host "$tab | $item copied." 
        }
    }
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Dlib
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

# Dlib library path:
$DLIB_PATH = 'C:\dlibAndroid\dlib'

function Compile-Dlib {
    Set-Location $DLIB_PATH
    Make-Dir 'build'

    Write-Host '=> Compiling Dlib...'
    sleep 0.5

    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "=> Compiling Dlib for ABI: '$abi'..."
        sleep 0.5

        Make-Dir "build\$abi"
        Set-Location "build\$abi"

        $cmakeArguments = @(
                "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1",
                "-DANDROID_NDK=$NDK",
                "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TOOLCHAIN",
                "-GNinja",
                "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
                "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-O3",
                "-DANDROID_ABI=$abi",
                "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-$MIN_SDK",
                "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=..\..\",
                "..\..\"
        )

        $stripArguments = @(
                "--strip-unneeded",
                "$DLIB_PATH/build/$abi/libdlib.so"
        )

        & $AndroidCmake $cmakeArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Generating the 'dlib/build/$abi/libdlib.so' for ABI: '$abi'..."
        & $AndroidCmake --build .
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host "=> Stripping libdlib.so for ABI: '$abi'to reduce space..."
        & $STRIPPERS[$abi] $stripArguments
        sleep 0.5

        Write-Host '=> done.'
        Set-Location ..\..\
        sleep 0.5
    }    
}

function Dlib-Setup {
    Write-Host '=> Making directories for Dlib...'
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include' created."
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib"
    Write-Host "=> '$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib' created."

    Write-Host "=> Copying Dlib headers..."
    Copy-Directory "$DLIB_PATH" "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\include\dlib" ''

    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libdlib.so' for each ABI..."
    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Copy-Item -Path "$DLIB_PATH\build\$abi\libdlib.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\dlib\lib\$abi"
        Write-Host " > Copied libdlib.so for $abi"
    }
}

# COMMENT TO DISABLE COMPILATION
Compile-Dlib

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- OpenCV
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# OpenCV library path: REPLACE WITH YOUR OPENCV PATH!
$OPENCV_PATH='C:\dlibAndroid\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native'

function Opencv-Setup {
    Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv"

    Write-Host "=> Copying 'libopencv_java4.so' for each ABI..."
    ForEach ($abi in $ABIs) {
        Make-Dir "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
        Copy-Item -Path "$OPENCV_PATH\libs\$abi\libopencv_java4.so" -Destination "$NATIVE_DIR\opencv\$abi"
        Write-Host " > Copied libopencv_java4.so for $abi"
    }
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Project setup
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Make-Dir $NATIVE_DIR

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY DLIB '.so' FILES
Dlib-Setup

# COMMENT TO NOT COPY OPENCV '.so' FILES
Opencv-Setup

Write-Host "=> Project configuration completed."

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When you run a .ps1 PowerShell script you might get the message saying “.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.”

To fix it you have to run the command below to run Set-ExecutionPolicy and change the Execution Policy setting.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```